# How to call a COM method (c++) in javascript code

Tags: javascript, c++, com

while developing my application which interacts with a COM server. I would like to return a value from a COM method and read it in the JavaScript code.

For instance:- 
STDIMPMETHOD class::Result(long*res)
{

```
*res = 2* 3;
return S_OK;
```

}

Javascript:-

var total= obj.result();

it is unable to recognize this even though it's a OUT param. however, I tried changing this to

obj.result(tot);

In this case, the function is being called in COM but how should i capture the return value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### You need to build a *web API server* which responses to your Java script AJAX request.

The web server will call the C++ code and return JSON. If you use Python for server, then try this [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/). For other server side language, it's also easy to google. Good luck!

Comment: i am just calling into a c++ com server and able to set the values , however, readig the value from the c++ to javascript is something which is not happening.

Comment: Nvermind ,i got the answer. There was a silly mistake which i did while returning the value from the COM method.